# Only google CDN link to jquery ui works on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I have used touch punch to get slider of jquery working in myiPad. But, it works only if I give :

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

And it doesn't work, if I try to use -

```
 <script src="./script/jquery-ui.js"></script>,
```

where jquery-ui.js is the downloaded file from http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js.

Comment: why dont you download file and include into your code ?

Comment: I have done the same and its not working for me. It loads only for the second time, not the first time.

Comment: Does it work on Web ( FF, Chrome , ... ) ?

Comment: No, its not working on Web if its FF, works fine in chrome

Comment: In your Ipad, can you see developer tool in browser ? If it has, please check if any errors display